# Is Mathematical Biology analogous to Mathematical Physics?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, biology

Mathematical Physics seeks to create mathematical tools and methods to solve physics problems. Is mathematical biology roughly analogous? Is mathematical biology the discipline that seeks to create mathematical tools and methods to solve biological problems? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, analogous in the sense you are asking (see, for example, the 2-volume *Mathematical Biology* by J. Murray).  However:

I. M. Gelfand, a mathematician who worked in biomathematics and molecular biology, as well as many other fields in applied mathematics, is quoted as stating,

``Eugene Wigner wrote a famous essay on the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in natural sciences. He meant physics, of course. There is only one thing which is more unreasonable than the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in physics, and this is the unreasonable ineffectiveness of mathematics in biology.[1]'' -- [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreasonable_ineffectiveness_of_mathematics)